# Without text, Jquery prevents input box trigger but not textarea trigger

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, textarea, inputbox

My input box uses placeholder text and jquery to ensure it doesn't trigger until I add text (i.e. not placeholder text).  I want to replace the input box with a text area but cannot get the jquery to work.  With the textarea below, the submit button triggers regardless of whether I type in the text area.

```
<div class="RepForm-loggedin" >
  <form name="RepForm" method="POST" action="<?php echo $this->newReply;?>">
    <table name="RepFormTable" style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <td style="width:100%">

    //CURRENT INPUT BOX
        <input type="text" rows="8"  id="repContent" class="inputbox inputbox-title placeholder-soc-med" name="repContent" placeholder="Ask a question . . ."/>

    //DESIRED REPLACEMENT TEXT AREA
        <textarea type="text" rows="8"  style="max-width:600px; width:100%" id="repContent" class="inputbox inputbox-title placeholder-soc-med" name="repContent" placeholder="Ask a question . . ."></textarea>

        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td style = "text-align:right;">
             <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="sendComment" class="dgrey-button">
         </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#sendComment').attr('disabled',true);
            $('#repContent').keyup(function(){
                if($(this).val().length !=0)
                    $('#sendComment').attr('disabled', false);
                else
                    $('#sendComment').attr('disabled',true);
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicated `id="repContent"`.

Your input box also has this ID. So, when you select your element with `$('#repContent')`, it is returning **only** your input field.

Just remove this attribute from the `<input />` and your code will work.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/7o493syd/1/

---

You may ask: **Why `$('#id')` does not select all elements with this ID?**

First of all, you can have only one element with the same ID in the document. From the [HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2):

> *id =* This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.

Then, when you select by id using jQuery, it will return just the first match (because it uses `document.getElementById()` internally). From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

> Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than
>   one element has been assigned the same ID, **queries that use that ID
>   will only select the first matched element in the DOM**. This behavior
>   should not be relied on, however; a document with more than one
>   element using the same ID is invalid.